# Setting up a CDN with Wagtail CMS

Tags: django, content-management-system, cdn, wagtail

I am looking into possibly setting up a CDN to use with my Wagtail sites. I am thinking that this will be a more efficient way to manage media uploads during stage/production pushes, since right now the media folder has to be manually copied from server to server on deploy. If all of the images were being accessed from a CDN then this wouldn't be an issue.

This would be my first time using a CDN so I'm looking for advice. There is lots of info on using a CDN with WordPress, but not a lot of documentation on setting one up with Wagtail/Django. I have the following questions about it:

1. Does anyone have any suggestions on the best way to implement the CDN with Wagtail?
2. How does it handle the uploads that the user submits through the CMS? Most of the images will be uploaded as part of the static files, but how does it work when the user uploads a photo as part of a post?
3. Which CDN companies have you had the best/worst experiences with? The sites I am planning to use this for are professional/business, but not e-commerce.

Also, if there is a more efficient way to handle the transfer of media uploads from one environment to another than using a CDN, I'd love to hear your suggestions for that too. As of right now I've had to copy the media folder over after doing the deploy, and I will have to do this every time I make a change to the site.

Thanks in advance for your assistance.

Answer (score 3):

The following resources can be helpful for your required setup in Wagtail (later on today I can provide you some more details):

**Frontend cache invalidator for pages (so not only for static and media files)**

Link: http://docs.wagtail.io/en/latest/reference/contrib/frontendcache.html#frontendcache-aws-cloudfront

**Storing media files in Amazon Web Services S3 buckets**

This should be a better solution instead of copying media files from server to server. In this case Amazon Web Services CloudFront (CDN) would be a perfect choice.

Link: https://django-storages.readthedocs.io/en/latest/backends/amazon-S3.html#amazon-s3

More info CloudFront: https://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/

**Static file cache invalidation with Django Whitenoise**

Can be relevant to clear the cache for a new deployment (the static files will have a unique filename so CDN will have a new file cache from its origin after the deployment)

Link: http://whitenoise.evans.io/en/stable/django.html

CloudFront from AWS will have my personal choice for CDN. Besides the awesome resources/services AWS has to offer, CloudFront is simple to setup and has one of the best CDN's out there.

Finally a CDN for serving static- and media files has nothing to do with Wagtail specifically. There are some (see list above) nice apps available for Django itself, but you are free to choose another CDN solution (like Cloudflare).

So setting up a AWS S3 Bucket for each environment (tst/acc/stg/prd) and use it for uploading you media files (so the files aren't on the server anymore) and setup a CloudFront distribution for these buckets would be a proper solution for your problem.

Best regards,
Rob Moorman

Comment: Can you please confirm that this solution would copy user-uploaded media files (images, documents) into the CDN and serve those files properly as well? It appears that Whitenoise is not suitable for serving user-uploaded “media” files.

Comment: User upload files (Django's media app) is not handled with Whitenoise. You should point your CDN to your (preferred) S3 Bucket for media files. In your Django application you have to setup that media files are uploaded to that same S3 Bucket, so instead of your servers local disc. You could use disc storage of the same server if you want, but I suggest to use a S3 Bucket.

So when you upload new files in Wagtail, they will have a new unique name on the S3 Bucket. If the end-user requests this media file via CDN the S3 Bucket origin is used.

Comment: CloudFront itself uses also S3 to cache her request. So if you want to use your disc for Django media files storage and NOT a separate S3 Bucket the CDN will cache it anyway. So if your Django sites goes down, the CDN will still serve your media files.

Comment: You can see a good example of CloudFront and Django media files on https://www.gazelleno1.com/